# how to decode json object using php

Tags: php, json

I am getting following  result from database:

```
stdClass Object ( [risk_challenge] => ["dfsgdfgdgdf","dfgdfgdfg","dfgdfgdfgdf"] )
```

When I tried to decode it with following function:

```
$result = json_decode($result,true);
```

I got this error:

```
Message: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Comment: first check your json. is it valid?

Comment: If it's an object, you've already decoded it. An instance of `stdClass` is a bona-fide PHP object, which you can iterate over, or access its members directly (`$obj->risk_challenge[0]`, for example)

Comment: You got your answer in your error message. You need to get string from database result to decode it, and you are giving object to it instead of string.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a valid *object*, there's nothing JSON about it, it's an instance of the core `stdClass` class of PHP. If you want to use it (for example get list the risk_challenge values) simply write:

```
foreach ($obj->risk_challenge as $value)
    echo ' *> ', $value, PHP_EOL;
```

Job done.
If you want to convert the object to an associative array, you have 2 options:

```
$array = (array) $object;//a simple cast
$array = json_decode( //decode with assoc argument = true
    json_encode(// but first encode it
        $object
    ), true);
```

Why would you use the second version instead of the cast? simple: A cast is shallow (if any of the properties/keys contains another object, it will *not* be cast to an associative array, but it'll remain an object. `json_decode` does work recursively. In your case, though, I'd stick to the cast.

Comment: how to call bootstrap modal in codeigniter controller function

Comment: @kalavathi: That's a different question all together, and probably one that has already been asked (or the answer to which is easily found in the manual).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to encode in json it is already decoded

use json_encode to encode